# ListLinePlot not showing one label in a cycle of points

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am using `ListLinePlot` to represent a closed circuit of points (forming a polyhedron). I am trying to label each node (point) of the cycle, but the node that is present twice gets no label.

This is my example:

```
ListLinePlot[{{11, 7}, {7, 9}, {15, 15}, {16, 12}, {11, 7}} -> {"A'", 
   "B'", "C'", "D'", " "}, 
 LabelingFunction -> 
  Callout[Automatic, Automatic, Appearance -> None], 
 Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}, AxesLabel -> {"z1", "z2"}, 
 Mesh -> Full, 
 GridLines -> Function[{min, max}, Range[Floor[min], Ceiling[max]]]]
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

I think the problem is with point `{11, 7}` (that should be labelled with "A'"), which appears twice in the main argument of the function `ListLinePlot`. I tried different approaches, but nothing seemed to work.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't seem to want the stem / leader feature from `Callout`, try `LabelingFunction -> Labeled` instead. The results are practically identical to what you show in your answer:

```
ListLinePlot[
  {{11, 7}, {7, 9}, {15, 15}, {16, 12}, {11, 7}} -> {"A'", "B'", "C'", "D'", ""},

  LabelingFunction -> Labeled, 

  Filling -> Bottom,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}},
  AxesLabel -> {"z1", "z2"},
  Mesh -> Full, 
  GridLines -> Function[{min, max}, Range[Floor[min], Ceiling[max]]]
]
```

[image: same figure, all labels showing]

Answer (score 3):

I found a way, using `Show`, which allows overlaying different plots:

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[{{11, 7}, {7, 9}, {15, 15}, {16, 12}, {11, 7}} -> {"A'",
     "B'", "C'", "D'", "-"}, 
  LabelingFunction -> 
   Callout[Automatic, Automatic, Appearance -> None], 
  Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}, AxesLabel -> {"z1", "z2"}, 
  Mesh -> Full, 
  GridLines -> Function[{min, max}, Range[Floor[min], Ceiling[max]]]],
 ListLinePlot[{{11, 7}} -> {"A'"}, 
  LabelingFunction -> 
   Callout[Automatic, Automatic, Appearance -> None], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}]
 ]
```

I get this:

[image]

Anyway, I think a solution without using *the `Show` hack* should be possible.